# Filtering multiple columns with Pg_Search in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filter

I am working on a project where we have to filter event based on location, date, sport, and skill level. At the moment each filter works individually but I I cannot chain them to get even more specific results.

This is what I have in my model.

```
 include PgSearch::Model
  pg_search_scope :global_search, 
  against: [:location, :sport, :level, :date]

  pg_search_scope :date_search,
  against: [:date]

  pg_search_scope :sport_search,
  against: [:sport],
  using: {
    tsearch: { prefix: true }
  }

  pg_search_scope :location_search,
  against: [:location],
  using: {
    tsearch: { prefix: true }
  }

  pg_search_scope :level_search,
  against: [:level]

  enum level: { Beginner: 1, Intermediate: 2, Advanced: 3, Pro: 4 }
```

And this is in my controller.

```
 def index
    if params[:search][:location].present?
      @events = policy_scope(Event).location_search(params[:search][:location])
    elsif params[:search][:sport].present?
      @events = policy_scope(Event).sport_search(params[:search][:sport])
    elsif params[:search][:date].present?
      @events = policy_scope(Event).date_search(params[:search][:date])
    elsif params[:search][:level].present?
      @events = policy_scope(Event).level_search(params[:search][:level])
     
    else
      @events = policy_scope(Event)
    end
  
    @markers = @events.geocoded.map do |event|
      {
        lat: event.latitude,
        lng: event.longitude
      }
    end
  end
```

And these are my filters

```
 <div id="collapseFilters" class="container collapse form">
    <%= simple_form_for :search, url: events_path, method: "GET", html: { class: 'form-block' } do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :date, as: :string, required: false, input_html: {class: "datepicker"} %>
      <%= f.input :level, collection: Event.levels.map{ |l| [l.first, l.second] }, required: false, label_method: :first, value_method: :second%>
      <%= f.input :location, required: false, placeholder: 'Enter a location for your event' %>
      <%= f.button :submit, 'Search', class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-form mt-3" %>
    <% end %>
    </div>
```

How could I chain them in the params so I could use more than one filter at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your controller:

```rb
def index
  @events = policy_scope(Event)

  @events = @events.location_search(params[:search][:location]) if params[:search][:location].present?  
  @events = @events.sport_search(params[:search][:sport]) if params[:search][:sport].present?
  @events = @events.date_search(params[:search][:date]) if params[:search][:date].present?
  @events = @events.level_search(params[:search][:level]) if params[:search][:level].present?

  @markers # ...
end
```

or even (if it is clear enough for you)

```rb
def index
  @events = policy_scope(Event)

  %i[location sport date level].each do |filter|
    next unless params[:search][filter].present?

    @events = @events.public_send("#{filter}_search", params[:search][filter])
  end

  @markers # ...
end
```

if I get  how this gem works  right.

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of pg_search. Yes, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use multisearchable option as described in documentation https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search